# What is the difference between reg_defaults and reg_defaults_raw in regmap facility?

Tags: linux-device-driver

When configuring `regmap`, it is possible to include a list of power on defaults for the registers.  As I understand it, the purpose is to pre-populate the cache in order to avoid an initial read after power on or after waking up.  I'm confused by the fact that there is both a `reg_defaults` and a `reg_defaults_raw` field.  Only one or the other is ever used.  The vast majority of drivers use `reg_defaults` however there's a small handful that use `reg_defaults_raw`.  I did look through the git history and found the commit that introduced `reg_defaults` and the later commit that introduced `reg_defaults_raw`.  Unfortunately I wasn't able to divine the reason for that new field.

Does anyone know the difference between those fields?